# An easy way of setting a ZPL template as landscape rather than portrait?

Tags: zpl

Is there a simple way of setting an entire label to print in landscape orientation rather than portrait? I tried the FWR method but it doesn't seem to affect it at all.

I get the feeling i'm going to have to completely realign my fields and graphic boxes if i want to make it landscape.

Answer (score 2):

`^FWr` command changes orientation of a field.

If you want to set whole label orientation, use `^POa` instead, like described e.g. in [Label Rotation and Orientation for ZPL based Desktop and Tabletop Printers](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO8075) document.

Answer (score 2):

The `^PO` command will only allow you to rotate in 180 degree increments, so that will not help you here.

Unfortunately, the answer to your question is "No." In order to switch between landscape and portrait modes, you will need to manually rotate/reposition/realign all your graphic boxes, text fields, and barcodes. (I feel your pain though, I've had to do this before and it is not fun.)

Comment: Thanks for the help - it wasn't a fun task!

Answer (score 0):

If your Zebra printer supports IPL (Intermec Printer Language), there is a rotation parameter you can use per object. For example, a barcode that is rotated 90 degrees. This is an excerpt from an XML I send to the printer.

```
<barcode Location="28,550" Symbology="Code128Auto" NarrowWidth="2" Height="90" PrintLabel="False" Rotation="90">
<data>Asset123</data> 
</barcode>
```